# What AP based champion can do the most damage in two seconds? not counting nunu or shaco.

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm trying to expand my champion pool but I want to find better champions, like Annie, that can kill someone in a single combo. Are there any other champions like this?

Comment: There're so many champions that can do such amount of damage in 2 seconds. After yor mentioned Annie, there's also Xerath, Lissandra, Syndra, Vel'Koz, Katarina, LeBlanc, Malphite, Anivia, Fizz, Diana, Veigar, Zyra, Rammus, Sejuani, Amumu. With proper build, timing and fingerspeed, you can instakill with any of those.

Comment: I main xerath, his damage isn't that big. I theorize that his damage has been reduced due to his range and AOE characteristics. His ap ratios are 45 to 75, not very impressive when people like ahri buttrape you in .5 seconds without any ap.

Comment: Ahri does even less damage than Xerath, since her abilities aren't beam-like and her spells have a small hitbox. In other words he can do more damage in teamfights than Ahri.

Comment: are you asking about single target or overall in a teamfight?

Answer (score 4):

Taking into account that Veigar and Thresh have no AP limitation, those two champions would deal the most Burst, however usually you won't get enough AP on Thresh to compete with other AP burst champions.

Veigar however would be the champion with the highest single target burst in a realistic scenario. His skills and Items:

```
Q: 260 + 60%  AP
W: 320 + 100% AP
R: 500 + 120% AP + 80% enemy AP
Deathfire Grasp: 20% of Target Health and + 20% magic damage increase
Lichbane: 75% Base AD + 50% AP (75% Base AD of veigar on lvl 18 = 71.625)
Arcane Blade: 5% AP
```

Can hit in under 2 seconds. It is very possible to gain 1000 AP in a game with veigar with a normal build but I wouldn't recommend buying Lichbane a lot but I'll include it here for the highest possible burst damage in under 2 seconds.

Now If you open up with DFG you'll already have 20% of the enemies HP and a 20% magic damage increase.

This means you can hit for a total of: **20% HP + 1381.95 + 392% AP + 96% Enemy AP** with DFG, Your Skills and an autoattack.

Let's say you're up against a Syndra on level 18 with 2000 HP, 600 AP and 100 Magic resistance while you have farmed up to get exactly 1000 AP.

If you full Combo Her you'd hit her for:

```
400 (20% HP) +
3920 (392 % of your AP) +
576 (96% of her AP) +
1382 (Base damage rounded up)
_______________________________
6278 Raw damage
```

Now even if you take her Magic resistance into account you'll still deal **3139 damage** which is pretty much an overkill. So this is one of the more realistic burst scenarios but of course it differs from situation to situation.

In the end most champions that are designed to burst someone down have a huge damage potential and are good at their role. You could take champions like Annie, Leblanc and even a Cho Gath can deal a huge amount of burst damage if played full AP. But Veigar  has the highest amount of burst within 2 seconds in a realistic scenario.

Comment: I frequently 100-0 people with Brand as well if he can get fed, and he also does mass AoE at the same time.

Comment: How does Veigar's ult rework affect these numbers?

Comment: @JamesENL See Veigar's page on [wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Veigar). His passive gains stacks more easily. Q = 230 + 60%, W = 300 + 100%, R = 375 + 75% (with *1.5% increased damage for every 1% of target's missing health, up to double damage against targets below 33.3% of their maximum health*). Also, DFG was removed from the game, and Lich Bane and Echo have changed.

Comment: In short, you need more stacks to hit previous damage levels, meaning you have to do better at farming and landing skill shots. Your ult deals less damage against enemy champions with AP (no longer taking their AP total into account), but more damage if they're missing health. So it's better to use R last.

Answer (score -3):

Ap ezreal does the most dmg to 5 people in 2 seconds.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail?

Comment: I would say that LB would do more assuming they are packed...

Answer (score -3):

I think that when you are get lulu's ult on you, dat you can kill a champion in 2 seconds, no matter who you are playing. But it is still cheating XD

Comment: Why/how is it cheating?